# Character array only contains last element after for loop, but works correctly inside loop

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++ (and stack overflow!), I'm working on a project and after much searching I cannot find what it is I'm not understanding. My problem is I have a character array that is being copied correctly inside a for loop, but as soon as the loop is over the char array will only contain several copies of the last element from the loop.

Apologies if this is a simple problem. Here's the portion of code giving me trouble. I tried to notate everything and trim the code to only what could be relevant. I cannot use strings for this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  //in file stream
#include <iomanip> //setfill
#include <cstring> //strcpy
#include <stdlib.h>  //srand and rand
#include <time.h>  //time for rand
#include <ctype.h> //toupper()
using namespace std;

const int MAXCHAR = 99; // max length of each element
const int CAP = 999; //max elements for char arrays
const int NUM_LOC = 3; // number of locations to generate

//combines adjectives and places into random locations
void getLocations(char adjectiveList[CAP][MAXCHAR], char placeList[CAP][MAXCHAR], int countAdjectives, int countPlaces,char locations[NUM_LOC][MAXCHAR]){
  int randAdj = 0, randPlace = 0; //initialize variables
  
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LOC; i++){ //runs three times
    randAdj = getRandNum(countAdjectives); //gets random numbers to choose with
    randPlace = getRandNum(countPlaces);
      
    for (int i=0; i<MAXCHAR;i++){ // this part works fine. makes the names uppercase
      adjectiveList[randAdj][i] = toupper(adjectiveList[randAdj][i]);
      placeList[randPlace][i] = toupper(placeList[randPlace][i]);
    }
        
    //combines adjective and place into one array element of locations[]
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_LOC;i++){
      strcpy(locations[i], adjectiveList[randAdj]);
      strcat(locations[i], " ");
      strcat(locations[i], placeList[randPlace]);
    }

    //testing to show the loop above is working
    cout << "locations[" << i << "] contains: " << locations[i] <<  endl;
   
  }
    //testing shows it only carries the last element out of the loop above
    cout << endl;
    cout << "locations[0] contains: " << locations[0] << endl;
    cout << "locations[1] contains: " << locations[1] << endl;
    cout << "locations[2] contains: " << locations[2] << endl;
}
```

Here's an example output:

```
locations[0] contains: GROTESQUE PORT
locations[1] contains: AVERAGE PAGODA
locations[2] contains: FIERCE PLAZA

locations[0] contains: FIERCE PLAZA
locations[1] contains: FIERCE PLAZA
locations[2] contains: FIERCE PLAZA
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: BTW, you can treat `std::string` as an array. :-)

Comment: The loop with the `strcpy` and `strcat` in it right under `//combines...` overwrites all of the entries every time. You need to remove that loop. If you were to print all 3 of the locations where you currently print one to say it's working in the loop you'd see the same issue.

Comment: It's also generally a bad idea to reuse the same variable name for loops inside other loops. Makes it harder to keep track of if it's the `i` for this loop, the outer loop, the loop outside that one, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> The loop with the strcpy and strcat in it right under //combines... overwrites all of the entries every time. You need to remove that loop. If you were to print all 3 of the locations where you currently print one to say it's working in the loop you'd see the same issue.

This did it. Thank you!